# Conversion Actions tab showing 'unverified' status

Tags: google-ads, conversions, click-tracking, google-ads-valuetrack

I have implemented the phone call conversion tracking code for my real estate website, as follows.

As instructed in Google ads guidelines, I have added the below code in `<head></head>` tags (Replaced `AW-CONVERSION_ID/CONVERSION_LABEL` with my conversion label):

```
<script>
function gtag_report_conversion(url) {
  var callback = function () {
    if (typeof(url) != 'undefined') {
      window.location = url;
    }
  };
  gtag('event', 'conversion', {
      'AW-CONVERSION_ID/CONVERSION_LABEL',
      'event_callback': callback
  });
  return false;
}
</script>
```

And added the below tags in text link, (Replaced phone number with my business number)

```
<a onclick="return gtag_report_conversion('tel:800-123-4567');" href="tel:800-123-4567">
```

I have implemented this two days before; But still, it's showing unverified status in conversion actions.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are using gtag.gs for Google Analytics? 
 https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs/

Comment: Yes., this is my analytics tag,                                                                   <script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-64250400-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-1');
gtag('config', 'AW-XXXXXXXXX');
</script>

Comment: Have you checked for errors in your browser developer tools console?